# Driver prog and method not behaving

Tags: java, methods, driver

```
public class FlightTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Flight info = new Flight(null, 0, null, null);
        String name = "Delta Airlines";
        int flightNum = 54663;
        String origin = "Dallas, TX";
        String destination = "Canton, MI";
        info.setDestination(destination);
        info.setFlightNum(flightNum);
        info.setName(destination);
        info.setOrigin(destination);
        System.out.print(info);
    }
}
```

The code above is my driver program.
Below is the method I'm using. I'm not sure if it is not being called correctly or not being named correctly.

```
public class Flight {

    private String name;
    private int flightNum;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;

    public Flight (String name, int flightNum, String origin, String destination) {
        name = "";
        flightNum = 0;
        origin ="";
        destination = "";
    }
    public enum Status {
        ONTIME, DELAYED, CANCELLED;
    }
    private Status flightStatus = Status.ONTIME;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public int getFlightNum() {
        return flightNum;
    }

    public void setFlightNum(int newFlightNum) {
        flightNum = newFlightNum;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String newOrigin) {
        origin = newOrigin;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String newDestination) {
        destination = newDestination;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The airline name is " +name+ ".\the flight number is " +flightNum+".\the origin is " + origin + ".\the destination is " +destination;
    }
}
```

The `.toString()` is cutting off the word "the" when printing, and all it prints out is "canton mi" for everything except flightnum, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

> *and all it prints out is "canton mi" for everything except flightnum, that is right*.

Well, you are setting everything to destination i.e. `"canton, mi"`:

```
    info.setDestination(destination); // destination
    info.setFlightNum(flightNum);     
    info.setName(destination);        // destination
    info.setOrigin(destination);      // destination
```

You need to populate your `info` with the right values:

```
    info.setDestination(destination);
    info.setFlightNum(flightNum);
    info.setName(name);
    info.setOrigin(origin);
```

Additionally, `\t` is just a tab so it's printed as blank space. Remove the leading `\`.

Comment: Works now! that fixed it, i should have noticed but didn't. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dev5564 happens to everyone. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You have `\t` in your string which is an escaped character. `\t` means tab, so your result is

```
The airline name is Canton, MI.{tab}he
```

You should remove the `\`.

Comment: ah okay, so that fixed the print output, now i just need to figure out why everything is being set to canton mi